# Как правильно расположить div-ы на сайте с помощью Flexbox

Tags: html, css3

задача: расположение div-ов в таком порядке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**т.е. высота header+nav статически всегда 120px(70+50), а высота sidebar,content и footer должны быть динамические. 
высота sidebar-а должен быть всегда до конца,а высота content-а в зависимости от содержания. footer должен быть прижат к низу окна.**
Примерно вот так: https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Но при моём коде получаю урезанный sidebar:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и, кроме этого, навигационный панель перекрывает статью контента:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Что с чем конфликтует не могу понять!

**HTML:**

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

 <!-- <head> -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello World</title>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">


 </head>



<body>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <div id="header">
   <img src="images/alphasoft.png" alt="picture" height="60px">

   <div id=reg_auth>
        <a href="" title="enter accountა">
            <div id="btn">
                sign in
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="" title="registration on the site">
            <div id="btn">
                registration
            </div>
        </a>

   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
      <ul class="nav_main_ul">
        <li><a href="">Main</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
  </div>

<div  id="wrapper">

  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu_list"><a href="">antiallergics</a>
          <ul class="menu_drop">
            <li><a class="file-link" title="aerius"    href="#erius">erius</a></li>
            <li><a class="file-link" title="claritine" href="#">claritine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ketotifen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">suprastin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">dimedrol</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

 <div  id="content-wrapper">
   <div id="content">

   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
 </div>

</div>


  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style:none;
    }
     html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #header{
        left:0; top:0;
        height:70px;
        width:100%;
        background:yellow;
    }

    #btn{
        float:right;
        margin-right:3%;
        margin-top:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
        padding:5px 9px;
        font-size:1em;
        background-color: #00004d;
        text-shadow:#454545 0 0 2px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(217, 91, 72, 1);
      }
    #wrapper {
        display: flex;
        /* flex-direction: column; */
        height: 100%;
      }
    #content-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 1000px;
      flex-grow: 1;
      }

    #sidebar {
        width: 200px;
        background-color:#00004d;
        border: 1px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
    #content {
        background:white;
        border: 1px solid black;
    /*    flex: 1 0 auto; */
    }

   #footer {
        background-color: #00004d;
        margin-top: auto;
        min-height: 100px;
        /* flex: 0 0 auto; */
    }

/* навигационный панель */

   #nav{
        left:0; top:120px;
        background-color: #00004d;
        width: 100%;
    }

   .nav_main_ul{
        position:relative;
        margin: 0px 0 0 400px;
    }
    #nav ul{
        height:50px;
        list-style:none;
        background-color: #00004d;
    }
    #nav li{
        display:block;
        float:left;
        font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:20px;
        position:relative;
    }
    #nav li a{
        color:#fff;
        display:block;
        height:50px;
        padding:0 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        line-height:50px;
    }
    .nav_main_ul li a:hover{
        background:#000080;
    }
    .submenu{
        position:absolute;
        width:250px;
    }
    .submenu li{
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background:#00004d;
    }
    .submenu li a{
        line-height:50px;
        height:50px;
        transition: background 0.5s;
    }
    .submenu li a:hover{
        background-color:red;
    }
    li:hover .submenu li{
        display:block;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .menu a{
      text-decoration:none; 
        background: #00004d; 
        color:#fff;
        padding:10px;
        display:block;
        border-bottom:1px solid #666;
        transition:0.5s all;
    }
    .menu a:hover{
        background:#666;
        padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    }

    /*вспливающее меню*/
    .menu_list{
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999;
    }
    .menu_drop{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:100%;
    top:-9999em;
    opacity:0; 
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    transition:0.5s opacity; 
    }
    .menu_list:hover .menu_drop{
    opacity:1;
    top:0;  
    }

    .menu_list:after{
        content:" ";
        position:absolute;
        border:5px solid; 
        border-color:transparent transparent transparent #eee; 
        top:1em;
        right:0.7em; 
        transition:0.5s;
    }
    .menu_list:hover::after{ 
        transform:scalex(-1); 
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте оставить в своём вопросе только тот код, который имеет к нему непосредственное отношение. По минимуму.

Comment: MAX, редактировал пост и максимально удалил лишний код.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно content и footer вынести в отдельный flex блок со свойством flex-direction: column; и этот отдельный блок поместить рядом с sidebar и так же обернуть во flex контейнер.

Для наглядности я все перекрасил и задал некоторые значения.
По-моему мнению должно быть приблизительно так, если конечно можно менять разметку:

```css
#header {
background-color: green;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
}

#nav {
background-color: silver;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper {
display: flex;
}

#sidebar {
width: 200px;
background-color: red;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
}

#content-wrapper {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
min-height: 1000px;
flex-grow: 1;
}

#content {
background-color: yellow;
min-height: 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
margin-top: auto;
background-color: blue;
min-height: 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 header header header header header header
  </div>

  <div id="nav">
      nav nav nav nav nav nav nav nav
  </div>

<div  id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
  sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar
  </div>

<div  id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    content content content content content
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  footer footer footer footer footer footer
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: l2banners, вроде всё поменял как вы сказали но почему-то, урезанный sidebar получаю и навигационный панель всегда открыта и перекрывает статью контента. 
Тему полностью обновил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Delphi159 у  #wrapper нужно убрать height: 100%; а насчет панели не понял что именно у вас не получается? У sidebar я задал для примера width: 200px; вы же под себя можете ставить или фиксированную ширину или вообще убрать чтобы она зависела от содержимого

Comment: @Delphi159 ах да, чтобы sidebar не сжимался меньше заданного размера нужно  добавить ему свойство flex-shrink: 0;

Comment: l2banners, с вашей помощью с sidebar-ом разобралься. Сейчас осталось только проблема навигационного панеля(div id="nav")- её субменю постоянно выдна на экране и перекрывает контент. (см.рисунок.)

Comment: @Delphi159 Ну меню нужно прятать и показывать когда наводите на его родителя например. Это уже немного другой вопрос.

Comment: так и был спрятан до перехода на flexbox. Как это повлял на его поведение не понял.

Comment: @Delphi159 никак ни могло повлиять, сравнивайте старое меню и новое